# Comment dire "marcher avec difficulté à cause de la fatigue"

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

Je cherche un mot pour exprimer marcher avec difficulté, à cause de la fatigue ou du douleur.

Je pense qu'en anglais on dirait : "to drag oneself".

J'ai trouvé le mot "se traîner", est-ce que ça marche ? 
Exemple :

> Je me suis traînée jusqu'à la cuisine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, pas mieux ! C'est la bonne expression :

[Traîner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tra%C3%AEner)

> **D.** − Empl. pronom.
>   **1.** [Le suj. désigne un animé]
>   ...
>   **b)** Avancer difficilement ou péniblement du fait d'une blessure, d'une infirmité, de l'âge. *Ne plus pouvoir se traîner; se traîner à (tel endroit). Un général (...) grièvement blessé à la jambe, s'était traîné au lever de l'Empereur* (Las Cases, *Mémor. Ste-Hélène*, t. 2, 1823, p. 364). *Le Percepteur: La fièvre, probablement. Il se traînait hier à la poste, en claquant des dents sous le gros soleil* (Lenormand, *Simoun*, 1921, 3etabl., p. 22).